# To create template with excel using python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

which library is used to create this template and how to do convert a series into drop down list with excel using python

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use openpyxl. openpyxl can be a little finicky when working with formating especially conditional formating.
You have tagged the post pandas so I guess you want to work with data frames and you can convert openpyxl to dataframes.

I will need more information to give a more specific answer, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this can be achieved using python pandas.

Sample code could be :

```
df = pd.read_csv("xyz/data.csv", usecols =["Techno", "Antennatype", .....])

x1 = widgets.Dropdown(options=df['Techno'])
x2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=df['Antennatype'])
display(x1)
display(x2)
```

Hope this could help!